# clustering based on web pages viewed together

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, association-rules

Let us say I know the number of pages users generally looked at in the same session over a period of time. I can obtain data like this:

```
P1, P2, 1000
P1, P3, 10
P1, P4, 0
P2, P3, 100
P2, P4, 0
```

Here

```
P1, P2, 1000
```

Means that Page1 and Page2 were looked at 1000 time by all users in the chosen time period.

Looking at the tiny sample above one could, for example, deduce that Page4 seems to be disjointed/very distant to the other pages, whereas P1 and P2 are close/similar.

I am just wondering whether the above could somehow be exploited to cluster similar pages. Ultimately, a page pair with a large number corresponds to some closeness.

What clustering algorithm could I use for this? I am only familiar with SOMs/k-means. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your overall goal, and what is the full dataset available,  eg do you have the pages viewed in each session?

Comment: The overall is to put pages viewed together into the same cluster. Sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: My question was why do you want to cluster the web pages together - if you don't specify that then its hard to identify the correct clustering.

Comment: You tagged your Q as `hierarchical clustering`. What prevents you to consider the option in your Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first think of the data as a graph i.e. the edge (P1, P2) would have weight 1000 in your example. You might already be doing this given the way your formatted the question.

After this, there are several graph clustering algorithms and libraries in the world. The Markov Clustering Algorithm seems to be the way to go about this even though I have never done it myself

http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~xyan/classes/CS595D-2009winter/MCL_Presentation2.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this as a graph as well. I will have a look.